# Inverting small matrices: canned factorization versus explicit formula

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, inverse

I am interested in solving a large number of small linear systems of equations, $Ax=b$, with $A$ either $2\times2$ or $3\times3$. Assuming none of these systems are actually singular, is there anything to deter me from forming $A^{-1}$ explicitly using Cramer's rule and computing $x=A^{-1}b$? The only things that comes to mind is possible loss of precision in the calculation of $\mathrm{det}A$. Can I expect any improvement over this naive approach by using a canned solver, e.g., LAPACK's `dgesv`? Namely, would doing so reap numerical benefits that justify the overhead of calling out to LAPACK?

(I am open to methodologies in between these two extremes as well, e.g., hard-coding Gaussian elimination).

Comment: Did you check the answer to [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5545/9667)?

Comment: Yes, I did. One answer (GertVdE's) does not actually address numerics. The other (Geoff's) does, but only in a cursory, qualitative way. I am hoping for more detail.

Comment: mind sharing a bit more detail about your problem? if you're doing e.g. computer vision and use GPUs, here's a thought: group your many matrices into _batches_ and use specialized code to process them all at once. this has been done. a couple of references to get the ball rolling: [Lemaitre et al. - batch Cholesky](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01361204/document), [Dong - batch LU](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/news_pub/submissions/batchedlu.pdf)

Comment: Intel's MKL (v2018) supports batch operations through _vectorized compact routines_, see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intelr-math-kernel-library-introducing-vectorized-compact-routines). another optimization technique (again, MKL-specific) is the use of [MKL_DIRECT_CALL's](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/improve-intel-mkl-performance-for-small-problems-the-use-of-mkl-direct-call). AFAIK, what this does is to disable error checking. The Intel folks report decent DGEMM speedups over the standard (non-direct?) MKL lib functions. YMMV.

Comment: anyway, to quote from [here](https://www.icl.utk.edu/files/publications/2017/icl-utk-1031-2017.pdf): "libraries compiled for specific sizes, either via templating or just-in-time (JIT) compilation, provide a large performance boost for small (matrix) sizes; for instance, Intel’s [libxsmm3](https://github.com/hfp/libxsmm) for extra-small matrix-multiply or batched BLAS for sets of small matrices. Thus, _users with such small matrices are encouraged to use special purpose interfaces rather than try to optimize overheads in a general purpose interface._"

Answer (score 2):

Cramer's rule using a more stable determinant:

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01500199/document

Implementation of the algorithm is consistently 2.5 times slower than LU factorization of matlab regardless of size of matrix.

Comment: To be precise, according to the data in the paper you linked, their Cramer's rule is faster than Matlab LU (whatever it's calling internally) for $N\lessapprox180$. However, I would be much more interested in comparison with an efficient LAPACK exactly for the matrix sizes of interest.